# Python Не могу получить инфо по индексу

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари, dict

`emj=drops["mine"][pickaxe["123"]].keys()[k]`

Выдает ошибку, если написать:

`emj=drops["mine"][pickaxe["123"]].keys()`

То все нормально выдает `dict_keys(['cobblestone', 'coal'])`

Но как мне обратиться к этому списку по индексу? Например как мне получить первое значение?

Comment: Можно весь список?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ну, понятно, что к словарю нельзя обращаться по индексу, в отличие от списка. Это в общем азы питона.

Answer (score 0):

`list(drops["mine"][pickaxe["123"]].keys())[k]`
Добавление функции `list()` помогло мне решить мою проблему.